# Editable Combobox with button to show popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

I need editable select box so that user can manually type in into it and also select from list of available options. What I have is drop-down with button inside it to open popup but along with this I also need manual input box.

Let us see how it looks

[image]

So right now I can only drop-down select list and open open pop-up, but it does not have editable input box there.

I am also sharing code and fiddle

```
<div class="grid-33">
              <label class="b-control">
                <span class="b-control__label">Source:</span>
                <span class="b-control__editable">
                  <select class="b-control__select">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="">...</option>
                    <option value="">...</option>
                    <option value="">...</option>
                  </select>
                  <a class="b-control__edit js-control__edit js-popupLink" href="#js-editSelect">...</a>
                </span>
              </label>
            </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mahendrakawde/o4j3x495/

to play with. Help me to have editable select with this css and js there in fiddle.

Comment: what is the role of Name and Seq # you are asking to input in model window?

Comment: Name will be new option that will get added into drop-down list and seq# will be auto generated number. But I am not concern about it. I only need input box element

Comment: @Siddharth I just need to have input box in front of button which shows popup, rest will be managed by js

Comment: can you add a pictorial diagram of what you want?

Comment: If you need not to support Safari, then you could use a normal input with a datalist and handling the enter key should get your job done with minimal fuss. See here for a demo -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/tg3pxk8x/

Answer (score 0):

mate i have tried something using CSS, but i am not really sure about the approach i have used, if it works for you then very well. please have a look at the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x2xkm30n/)

```
<input class="edit_text" type="text"/>
```

> and corresponding  CSS

```
.edit_text{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 34px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  width: 246px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

i have introduced an external input and then tried to overlay it existing select, looking fine working fine, now you can add events to input for searching in select tag items and whatnot, basically you can do anything you want with that input tag.

Comment: This did not worked when I added it to whole page. For a single element it does works.

Comment: Can you suggest about editable dropdown with button inside ?

Comment: you need to change the css when you add it to whole page and it should work, just change the top element of css according to the situation available. well did you check [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Comment: By changing CSS it mess out my whole page. I saw chosen but my problem is i need button also inside select so as to invoke poup

Comment: can you make a fiddle of the page you are working on, man nothing is messy, you need to apply the correct rules.

Comment: Hey friend I made it worked out by changing CSS of yours. Now the thing is I have lot of such fields where I need such text boxes but the problem is every field has different width. So in such case how can I make it work for all by doing changes only once

Comment: i think you can write generic jquery script for the same, use DOM manipulation, get the width of field by using jquery and apply it on input field using jquery again, if it worked for you kindly mark it as right answer. thanks.

Comment: one more thing is that when I select item from list it does not shows as text box is hiding select element, any selected option does not appears on the page.

Comment: well that was what i was fearing this is an UX flaw, i think you can change the position of select or, put the selected value inside input box using jquery. many solution pal.

Comment: Is there any concrete solution available for this kind of scenario. Or this is just first requirement you also encountered ?

Comment: i do not think so, well people use chosen for the same, chosen has input for search but none for adding, i am encountering this scenerio for the first time, if you know your CSS game, you can always make it look good, not a big play mate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99682/discussion-between-siddharth-and-mahendra-kawde).